# Selecting mysql data with php array not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

For some reason this code isnt working and I dont know why:

```
$action = array('id', 'lurl', 'account');
$request = 3;
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ? FROM (SELECT * FROM urls ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?) sub ORDER BY id ASC");
$stm->bindValue(1, implode(',', $action));
$stm->bindValue(2, $request, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->execute();
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

All it does is return the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id,lurl,account] => id,lurl,account ) [1] => Array ( [id,lurl,account] => id,lurl,account ) [2] => Array ( [id,lurl,account] => id,lurl,account ) )
```

But when I manually enter the data in a query like so:

```
SELECT id,lurl,account FROM (SELECT * FROM urls ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3);
```

It does what it is supposed to. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: The whole code is wrong, please learn more about PDO appropriately.

Comment: as far as I understand PDO, parameters are not to be used to specify DB-fields to be selected.

Comment: @michi Oh I thought they could, I guess I'll just put the data right into the query without passing it through pdo.

Comment: PDO has a real issue with binding column and table names. It can't be done like this.

Answer (score 0):

With bindValue you can only bind "values" and not references. To bind references you need to use bindParam

**change:**

```
$stm->bindValue(1, implode(',', $action));
$stm->bindValue(2, $request, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

**to:**

```
$stm->bindParam(1, implode(',', $action));
$stm->bindParam(2, $request, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll remember that but it still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Don't know if you can nest your query like that. Build it up step by step. Start with simple logic and bind parameters and then take it a step further.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the imploded string gets quoted, this is the main problem.
you can fix the problem this way:

```
    $actions = array('id', 'lurl', 'account');

    $fields = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($actions), '?'));

    $request = 3;

    $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT " . $fields . " FROM (SELECT * FROM urls ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?) sub ORDER BY id ASC");

    foreach ($actions as $key => $action)
        $stm->bindValue(($key+1), $action);

    $stm->bindValue(2, $request, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();

    $data = $stm->fetchAll();
```